# How to use a literal string argument in a Typescript generic constraint for deep object path?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write an object path utility that guarantees that the list of keys corresponds to an actual path in the specified generic type.

In my attempt below, I think the generic signature is widening the inferred literal string value to simply be `string`. How can I use the literal string argument in my generic constraint to ensure that the next key is a key of the previous key's value?

```js
class FieldPathBuilder<C,
  K1 extends string & keyof C = string & keyof C, // ensure first arg is a valid top-level key
  K2 extends string & keyof C[K1] = string & keyof C[K1], // must be a valid key of C[K1]
> {

  path(key1: K1, key2?: K2): string {
    return '' // not important
  }
}

interface A {
  first: {
    second: {
      third: {}
    }
  },
  other: {} // NOTE: the example below compiles if I remove this field
}

new FieldPathBuilder<A>().path('first', 'second') // <-- Error: Argument of type
// '"second"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to this approach (safe path builder):

```
interface PathResult<T> {
  isSafe: boolean;
  path: any[];
  <TKey extends keyof T>(subkey: TKey): PathResult<T[TKey]>;
}

/**
 * Create a deep path builder for a given type
 */
export function safePath<T>(root: T) {
  /**Returns a function that gets the next path builder */
  function subpath<T, TKey extends keyof T>(parent: string[], subRoot: T, key: TKey): PathResult<T[TKey]> {
    const newPath = [...parent, key as string];
    let newRoot: T[TKey];
    let isSafe: boolean;
    if (isSafe = (subRoot && subRoot[key] !== undefined)) {
      newRoot = subRoot[key];
    } else {
      isSafe = false;
    }
    const x = (<TSubKey extends keyof T[TKey]>(subkey: TSubKey) => subpath<T[TKey], TSubKey>(newPath, newRoot, subkey)) as PathResult<T[TKey]>;
    x.path = newPath;
    x.isSafe = isSafe;
    return x;
  }

  return <TKey extends keyof T>(key: TKey) => subpath<T, TKey>([], root, key);
}

interface MyInterface {
  person: {
    names?: {
      lastnames?: {
        first: string;
        second: string;
      }
      firstname: string;
    }
    age: number;
  }
  other: string;
}

// example 2
const test: MyInterface = {
  person: {
    age: 123
  },
  other: 'foo'
};
const res2 = safePath(test)('person')('names')('lastnames')('second');
console.log(res2.path); // ["person", "names", "lastnames", "second"]
console.log(res2.isSafe); // false

// example 3
const res3 = safePath(test)('person')('foo')('lastnames')('second'); // compile error
console.log(res3.path); // ["person", "foo", "lastnames", "second"]
console.log(res3.isSafe); // false

// example 4, type `(` the ctrl + space see suggestions for "person" and "other"
const res4 = safePath(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that the generic key constraints were declared at the class level rather than at the function, which I'm assuming prevented the compiler from inferring the string types as literal values because the keys aren't provided until the following function call.

#### ✅ Move key type constraints from the class to the function

```js
interface A {
  first: { second: { third: {} } },
  other: {}
}

class FieldPathBuilder<C> {

  path<K1 extends string & keyof C, K2 extends string & keyof C[K1]>(
    key1: K1,
    key2?: K2,
  ): string {
    return '' // not important
  }
}

new FieldPathBuilder<A>().path('first', 'second') // ✅
new FieldPathBuilder<A>().path('other', 'second') // ❌ "second" isn't key of "other"
```

#### ❌ Keep key type constraints at the class-level and accept keys in constructor

It might have been cleaner to pass the keys to the constructor but that would require the keys to have been passed as both generic type arguments and function arguments because all non-default generic types must be provided if one is provided. In this case `A` is given so we would also need to provide the explicit key types.

While this works, it isn't the solution I'm looking for because you're required to specify each key twice.

```js
interface A {
  first: { second: { third: {} } },
  other: {}
}

class FieldPathBuilder<
  C,
  K1 extends string & keyof C,
  K2 extends string & keyof C[K1]
> {
  constructor(key1: K1, key2?: K2) {}
}

new FieldPathBuilder<A>('first', 'second') // ❌ Expected 3 type arguments, but got one
new FieldPathBuilder<A, 'first', 'second'>('first', 'second') // ✅
```

#### ❌ Use default key types

Typescript supports default type arguments so we could attempt to avoid the redundant string type arguments by setting a default.

```js
class FieldPathBuilder<C,
  K1 extends string & keyof C = string & keyof C, //  default
  K2 extends string & keyof C[K1] = string & keyof C[K1] //  default
> {
  constructor(key1: K1, key2?: K2) {}
}

new FieldPathBuilder<A>('first', 'second') // ❌
```

However, this still won't compile because (I think) the default key types are now widened to the non-literal key string values (`string` instead of `"first"`...).